# Is the gradient correctly computed?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, convex-optimization

The function is $\frac{1}{1+\|x_i-c_{yi}\|_2^2}$.
Following my computation of the gradient w.r.t. $x_i$. Can somebody please check if it is correct. Let $u = 1+||x_i-c_{y_j}||_2^2$, thus $f = u^{-1}$.

\begin{gather}
    = \frac{\partial u^{-1}}{\partial u}\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}({1+||x_i-c_{y_j}||_2^2}) \\ 
    \frac{\partial (u^{-1})}{\partial u} = \frac{-1}{u^2} \\
    \frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}(1+||x_i-c_{y_j}||_2^2) = 2{(x_i-c_{y_j})}
\end{gather}
Substituting these values, the final equation becomes $\frac{-1}{u^2}(2(x_i-c_{y_j}))$. We can simplify this equation to obtain the final gradient which is:
$$= \frac{-2(x_i-c_{y_j})}{(1+(x_i-c_{y_j})^2)^{2}}$$
Can anybody please confirm if the calculation is mathematically sound?
Also, since the Hessian would be $\Delta^2f(x)<0$, so this is a concave function. Am I correct?

Thanks.

Comment: can't you just check it numerically? and I don't see the Hessian so how do you know it is negative?

Comment: the derivative looks as expected. You can also cross-check here http://www.matrixcalculus.org

Comment: You haven't proven that the Hessian is negative definite, so you certainly cannot conclude this is concave without further evidence. In fact I doubt that it is.

Comment: Also, is $x_i$ a scalar or a vector? If the former, why the norm notation $\|\cdot\|$? Isn't this just an absolute value in that case?

Comment: It is a vector, $c_{y_j}$ is also a vector which is sampled from the same distribution as $x_i$. 
Thanks for the input, I think I got the answer.